# Assign return of Matrix::row() to Matrix<X,1,Dynamic>

Tags: c++, eigen

I'm writing a method that takes as an argument a row Matrix, such as:

```
method(Matrix<float,1,Dynamic>& rowMatrix);
```

If I try to invoke the method with the result of Matrix.row(x), such as:

```
Matrix<float,Dynamic,Dynamic> matrix(2,2);
method(matrix.row(1));
```

I get the following error:

```
no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1> >::ColXpr {aka Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1>, -1, 1, true, true>}’ to ‘Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, 1>&’
```

I understand that the problem here is that I'm trying to assign a reference to `Matrix<float,1,Dynamic>` to a `ColXpr`, which seems not to be valid. I can "solve" the problem by passing by value, in which case I guess a new Matrix is constructed taking the `ColXpr` as argument constructor and everything works fine.

I'm not modifying the matrix inside the method, so passing by value is "acceptable". However, I would like to pass by reference in order to avoid copying the data and increase performance. Is there any way of converting from the return of `Matrix::row()` to anything assignable to `Matrix<datatype,1,Dynamic>&`?

Answer (score 3):

That's not possible, but there are two options for you:

1. Make your function template as explain in Eigen [manual](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/TopicFunctionTakingEigenTypes.html).
2. If writing a template function is not possible for you, then the [Ref<>](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/classEigen_1_1Ref.html) class available in the devel branch is the right answer. Basically, it boils down to:

   `method(Ref<Matrix<float,1,Dynamic>, 0, InnerStride> rowMatrix);`

   or a const version:

   `method(const Ref<const Matrix<float,1,Dynamic>, 0, InnerStride<> >& rowMatrix);`

Comment: Thanks, you'll definitely pointed me into the right direction

Comment: Actually, in you make the parameter const I think you don't need to use Ref (at least it works without it in my case).

Comment: Sure it will work but it will introduce a temporary and a copy.

Comment: I'm not sure it would make a copy. If it's `const Matrix<float,1,Dynamic> &` it's a reference, it shouldn't be making a copy, should it?

Comment: yes it will because row() returns a Block<> object which is not the same type as Matrix<>. Moreover, the memory layout of these two objects are not compatible, thus the introduction of the Ref<> class.